# Is there a word for a property of an algorithm where the output of the algorithm does not depend on the order of the input?

Tags: algorithms, terminology

I'm looking for a word to describe an algorithm that takes an ordered list as input, where the output depends on the content of the list but not the order. A sorting algorithm on integers would be an example of such an algorithm, because a sorting algorithm will always output the same output list for any input list that contains the same integers, whatever order that input happens to have. An algorithm that returns the greatest difference between two adjacent integers in a list would be an example that does not have this property.

Essentially I want a word that means 'insensitive to input order'. 'Deterministic' and 'Idempotent' are close to what I want but not exactly correct.

Comment: Permutation invariant ?